# Unable to connect to source.repository.backtrack-linux.org

Tags: linux, apt, aptitude, backtrack

I have a BackTrack5 r3 installed on VMware.
As you see below  I have internet access in it :

```
root@bt:~# ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (173.194.70.105) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from fa-in-f105.1e100.net (173.194.70.105): icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=205 ms
64 bytes from fa-in-f105.1e100.net (173.194.70.105): icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=208 ms
64 bytes from fa-in-f105.1e100.net (173.194.70.105): icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=208 ms
64 bytes from fa-in-f105.1e100.net (173.194.70.105): icmp_seq=4 ttl=128 time=209 ms
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 205.799/208.145/209.851/1.473 ms
```

The question is, why when I try to use **`apt-get update`** command, I receive error?!

```
root@bt:~# apt-get update 
Err http://32.repository.backtrack-linux.org revolution Release.gpg            
  Could not connect to 32.repository.backtrack-linux.org:80 (50.7.55.50). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err http://32.repository.backtrack-linux.org/ revolution/main Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to 32.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:
Err http://32.repository.backtrack-linux.org/ revolution/microverse Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to 32.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:
Err http://32.repository.backtrack-linux.org/ revolution/non-free Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to 32.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:
Err http://32.repository.backtrack-linux.org/ revolution/testing Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to 32.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:
Err http://source.repository.backtrack-linux.org revolution Release.gpg        
  Could not connect to source.repository.backtrack-linux.org:80 (50.7.55.50). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err http://source.repository.backtrack-linux.org/ revolution/main Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to source.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:
Err http://source.repository.backtrack-linux.org/ revolution/microverse Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to source.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:
Err http://source.repository.backtrack-linux.org/ revolution/non-free Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to source.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:
Err http://source.repository.backtrack-linux.org/ revolution/testing Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to source.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:
Err http://all.repository.backtrack-linux.org revolution Release.gpg           
  Could not connect to all.repository.backtrack-linux.org:80 (50.7.55.50). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err http://all.repository.backtrack-linux.org/ revolution/main Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to all.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:
Err http://all.repository.backtrack-linux.org/ revolution/microverse Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to all.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:
Err http://all.repository.backtrack-linux.org/ revolution/non-free Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to all.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:
Err http://all.repository.backtrack-linux.org/ revolution/testing Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to all.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://all.repository.backtrack-linux.org/dists/revolution/Release.gpg  Could not connect to all.repository.backtrack-linux.org:80 (50.7.55.50). - connect (111: Connection refused)

W: Failed to fetch http://all.repository.backtrack-linux.org/dists/revolution/main/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to all.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://all.repository.backtrack-linux.org/dists/revolution/microverse/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to all.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://all.repository.backtrack-linux.org/dists/revolution/non-free/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to all.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://all.repository.backtrack-linux.org/dists/revolution/testing/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to all.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://32.repository.backtrack-linux.org/dists/revolution/Release.gpg  Could not connect to 32.repository.backtrack-linux.org:80 (50.7.55.50). - connect (111: Connection refused)

W: Failed to fetch http://32.repository.backtrack-linux.org/dists/revolution/main/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to 32.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://32.repository.backtrack-linux.org/dists/revolution/microverse/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to 32.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://32.repository.backtrack-linux.org/dists/revolution/non-free/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to 32.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://32.repository.backtrack-linux.org/dists/revolution/testing/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to 32.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://source.repository.backtrack-linux.org/dists/revolution/Release.gpg  Could not connect to source.repository.backtrack-linux.org:80 (50.7.55.50). - connect (111: Connection refused)

W: Failed to fetch http://source.repository.backtrack-linux.org/dists/revolution/main/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to source.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://source.repository.backtrack-linux.org/dists/revolution/microverse/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to source.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://source.repository.backtrack-linux.org/dists/revolution/non-free/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to source.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://source.repository.backtrack-linux.org/dists/revolution/testing/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to source.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:

W: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried to open [source.repository.backtrack-linux.org](http://source.repository.backtrack-linux.org) with my internet browsers, but I receive `The requested URL could not be retrieved` and `Unable to connect`. So I guess the origin of the problem is in the Backtrack support. but what shall I do now?

Comment: Get the new version of Backtrack called "Kali" may be the best...

Comment: @Con7e Did you mean the previous backtrack is going on to join to the history? (I mean there be be no any support for it anymore?)

Comment: It's exactly what I am saying sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backtrack 5 was 'killed off' along with all its downloads. You can now use http://www.kali.org which is the new backtrack org. release for penetration and testing for all old backtrack as well as new features.